# Display date format as DD MM YYYY in active record Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, datetime

How would I alter my active record to display my date as DD MM YYYY rather than YYYY MM DD?

**Current Display**

*2016-01-07*

**Aim Display**

*07-01-2016*

**Current**
**View**

```
<?php echo $row->start_date; ?>
```

**Tried**
**View**

```
<?php echo $row->DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%d/%m/%Y'); ?>
```

**Model**

```
class Profiles_model extends CI_Model

    {

        function get_bank()
        {
            $this->db->where('mem_id', $this->session->userdata("id"));
            $query = $this->db->get('bank');
            return $query->result();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What happens with what you tried that didn't seem to work?

Comment: No, dose not change anything

Comment: `var_dump($row->start_date)`, If it is a string you need to look at formatting earlier than view or converting the string to a DateTime and using a formatter. If the `start_date` is already a DateTime, use the `format` method. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) and [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) of php as :

```
$originalDate = $row->start_date;
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Answer (score 4):

I always prefer to make a helper function in Codeigniter for date formatting because date is very common to use on many pages.

**Codeigniter 3 helper function:**

```
if(!function_exists('dateFormat'))
{
    function dateFormat($format='d-m-Y', $givenDate=null)
    {
        return date($format, strtotime($givenDate));
    }
}
```

Autoload this helper in your Codeigniter autoload.php and then use it freely anywhere in controller/model/view.

use in view like:

```
<?= dateFormat('d-m-Y',$info->createdDtm) ?>
```